# Difference between &g:filetype and &filetype

Tags: filetype, set

Right now I have a python (*.py) file buffer open in a vim session. I also have the plugin startify installed.

Now when I run the Ex-command:

```
echo &g:filetype`
```

I get `startify`.

However, When I run

```
echo &filetype
```

I get `python`.

I have tried doing `setl filetype?` and `set filetype?`, I get `python` for both. <del>So it is not an issue of local vs global setting.</del> I can't seem to find anything relevant the docs for `'filetype'` or `:set`.

Once I run `set ft=python` on the buffer, both `echo &ft` and `echo &g:ft` start displaying `python`.

How can this be explained? What am I missing?

PS: I am using vim 8.0(1-133) on windows 7.

Comment: and finally, what does `setg filetype?` return?

Comment: yes `setg filetype` gets me `startify`! I was not aware of `:setg`! thanks